# How to animate div using with two arrow icons one is for open one is for close?

Tags: jquery

I am doing some div animating using jquery animate in middle i struck can any one help on this to continue.

my requirement will be when i clicked arrow icon div should animate. After animate div collapse the left side arrow needs to show for closing the collapsed place.

i have added two images one is for open and another one is for closing.

JsFiddle Link

http://jsfiddle.net/CZpdF/1/

Comment: You should consider making a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so it's easier for us to debug.

Comment: sure! I will edit and save it again.

Comment: please look at this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CZpdF/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#buying-power-right, #buying-power-left").click(function() {
    $(this).attr('id', function() {
        return this.id == 'buying-power-right' ? "buying-power-left" : "buying-power-right";
    });
    $("#buying-power-content").animate({
        width: 800
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 200
    }).toggle();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xfyq3/7/)**

Comment: when clicked on arrow that arrow should hide and want show the another arrow for close the animate but you have used toggle.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply..almost it reached but here you have used like this .width() == 353 ? 800 : 353; is there any other option because present i am looking this example in 1024 screen that content is showing down when clicked on arrow also that closing you have used arrow that absolutely right but when it closing it's directly hiding but not animate wise closing.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. did you observe first time animate working good but if you click second time on-wards that animate is not working only toggle type it's showing

Answer (score 0):

`#buying-power-content` has `display:none;`

You have to show it in your click event.

```
$("#buying-power-content").show().animate({width:800}, { queue: false, duration: 200 });
```